# Received a label value of 17 which is outside the valid range of [0, 12) - Keras Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras is unfamiliar to me. I'm attempting to put some programming into action.

The data shape is as follows:

```
Train shape X: (249951, 5, 52)  y  (249951,)
Test shape X: (263343, 5, 52)  y  (263343,)  # Do not confuse with the distribution, it is juts toy example
```

My date contains **twelve labels**. The keras CNN architecture is as follows:

```
def get_compiled_model():
    # Make a simple 2-layer densely-connected neural network.
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(260,))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(12)(x)    # 12  classes
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )
    return model
```

Now, I feed 12 neuron to the output layer, as my data contains 12 classes. However, the following error message is displayed:

```
    Use `tf.data.Iterator.get_next_as_optional()` instead.
2255/7811 [=======>......................] - ETA: 18s - loss: 0.1109 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.99452021-04-19 16:32:33.591493: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at sparse_xent_op.cc:90 : Invalid argument: Received a label value of 17 which is outside the valid range of [0, 12).  Label values: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 17 17 17 17 17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2804, in variable_creator_scope
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 807, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 17 which is outside the valid range of [0, 12).  Label values: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 17 17 17 17 17
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py:932) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_846]
Function call stack:
train_function
```

**Main Error:**
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 17 which is outside the valid range of [0, 12).  Label values: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 17 17 17 17 17

Comment: The output Dense layer with 12 units should have the 'softmax' activation function for multi class classification tasks.

Comment: In reality, I am copying the code that has been applied on the imnist data set and modifying it to fit the time serius classification data. Therefore, do I need to use softmax in the output layer?

Comment: I edit with this `outputs = keras.layers.Dense(12, activation="softmax")(x) `, but still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your label(y) is numeric, it will not work. You need to convert it to binary data, since it is multiclass binary problem.
Maybe you can use below to do so.

```
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

`num_classes` is 12, in your case.
However, 12 classes sound too many for me. Is this really multiclass, rather than multilabel?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is human activities, so it is multi-class. Let me try then will let you know.

Comment: @ Shinichiro Imoto, I am facing another problem for CNN, Code is `cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernal_size = 3,
                     input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], X_lstm_train.shape[1], X_lstm_train.shape[2], 1), activation="relu"))`, Error is : `cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernal_size = 3,
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kernel_size'`. Could you please why it is coming and how can we solve it

Comment: It is a time series classification problem, but you are adding Conv2D and it ‘kernal_size’ you assign is not tuple and input shape does not make sense to me.
I believe that it should be Conv1D w/ TimeDistributed() wrapper, since time is 1 dimension. I recommend you to check and utilize TF official tutorial below. It will help you and helped me long time ago as well.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series
Also Jason Brownlee PhD always helps me.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/